# Proving Limits of f(x) and f(a+h) are equal

Tags: calculus, limits, elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-verification

The question asks me to prove that the equality of these two expressions $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{h \to 0}f(a+h)$ provided their limits exist.

My answer:

Let $x=a+h$ so this $\lim_{h \to 0}f(a+h)=lim_{x-a \to 0}f(x)= \lim_{x \to a}f(x)$. $\square$

My qualms with this proof is that I set $x=a+h$ based on the assumption that $f(x)$ and $f(a+h)$ are equal functions. Is this assumption valid or am I doing circular reasoning ? Also assuming I have a function $f(x)$ and $f(w+z)$ is it $always$ safe to make the assumption $x=w+z$ as the two functions are the same(since $f$ is a set of ordered pairs) except what is inside the parenthesis.

Comment: it is obvious..

Comment: @Lemur So I am not doing any circular reasoning. I am asking since I tend to do a lot of circular reasoning without knowing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a totally formal proof then use the $\epsilon $, $\delta$ definition of limit.

Assume firstly that $\lim_ {x→a} f(x)$ exists and = $L$. Then given any $\epsilon > 0$ you can find a corrsponding $\delta$ such that for all $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ you have $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Now let $h = x -a$ so that $x = h + a$

Then given any $\epsilon > 0$ you can find a corrsponding $\delta$ such that for all $ 0 < |h + a-a| = |h|< \delta$ $|f(h+a) - L| < \epsilon$. In other words, $\lim_{h \to 0}f(a+h) = L$ = $\lim_ {x→a} f(x)$

Comment: I think you have to write $0 \le |x-a| < \delta$ ($x$ may also be $a$ which is necessary if there is no sequence $(x_n)$ in $D\setminus\{a\}$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n=a$, $D$ is the definition set)...

Comment: @tampis greater than but not equal. If you include equality you require the function to be continuous, but it can have a limit without being continuous. Consider $sin(x)/x$. Unless you define it as 1 at $x=0$ you will have a problem with allowing equality.